# ASP.Net MVC DataAnnotation Client side Validation not triggering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, client-side-validation

Question might seem lengthy, but i have tried to cover all aspects.
I am stuck on this issue for more than a couple of days and i don't know why but my DataAnnotations are not working on client side even though the code is generated for them and ModelState.isValid also returns false in Controller.
I have added the following lines in my _Layout file after searching on internet one by one.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@{
   Html.EnableClientValidation();
   Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
}
```

And data annotations in Model are like:

```
public class PasswordChangeObject
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    //[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String oldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "New Password is required")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public String newPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirming New Password is required")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("newPassword", ErrorMessage="Passwords do not Match!")]
    public String confirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And in my cshtml file i have fileds like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "ChangePass", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "chanegPassForm" }))
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @*<input type="password" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Old Password" required>*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.oldPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Old Password", @type = "password", @required = "true" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(vm => vm.oldPassword)
                </div>
            </div>
                <span class="help-block">Old Password</span>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @*<input type="password" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="New Password" required>*@
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.newPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "New Password", @type = "password", @required = "true" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(vm => vm.newPassword)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="help-block">New Password</span>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @*<input type="password" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Re-Type New Password" required>*@
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(vm => vm.confirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Re-Type New Password", @type = "password", @required = "true" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(vm => vm.confirmPassword)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="help-block">Re-Type New Password</span>
                <button id="changePasswordSubmitbtn" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="padding-top: 5px;" type="submit">Change Password</button>

        }
```

And finally the Scripts are included too...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/headroom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/jQuery.headroom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

And yes, Html is being generated like:

```
<form action="/User/ChangePass/ChangePassword" id="chanegPassForm" method="post">                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Password is required" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" required="true" type="password" value="" />
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="oldPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
                <span class="help-block">Old Password</span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="Must be between 5 and 255 characters" data-val-length-max="255" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="New Password is required" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" required="true" type="password" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="newPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="help-block">New Password</span>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="Passwords do not Match!" data-val-equalto-other="*.newPassword" data-val-length="Must be between 5 and 255 characters" data-val-length-max="255" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="Confirming New Password is required" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Re-Type New Password" required="true" type="password" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="confirmPassword" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="help-block">Re-Type New Password</span>
                <button id="changePasswordSubmitbtn" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="padding-top: 5px;" type="submit">Change Password</button>
</form>
```

Now, please help me out of this situation.
**EDIT**
I forgot to tell that only required is working nothing else.

Comment: You should remove the `@required = "true"` from all your controls - that is HTML-5 validation only and not jquery validation (which is why your seeing an error message) and use `@Html.EditorFor()` or `@Html.PasswordFor()` for your `newPassword` and `confirmPassword` properties (and delete `@type = "password"`) and remove the `[Required]` and `[StringLength]` attributes from `confirmPassword` (they are not necessary because the you have a `[Compare]` attribute).

Comment: The fact that your form tag does not have the `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute suggest that there is a problem with your scripts (that attribute is added by `jquery.validate.js`)

Comment: Alright, i will update you ater doing all this, besides, i have not included custom js files, these are as it is as i got them.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the properties to enable ClientValidation and UnobtrusiveJavaScript in your Web.config (appSettings section) instead of layout like this:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

I tried in my own project to remove these lines in web.config and enable them with HTML helpers in layout view like you.

Maybe there is specific place where these helpers should be used. 
Maybe something is not loaded yet and validation is not enabled correctly.

Comment: Well then you can remove the ones in layout because they are not necessary then.

Comment: What is the model of your View? Is it PasswordChangeObject? Also is this view invoked normally or is maybe it's loaded with Ajax? Could you show your controller action?

Comment: No ajax in this view is used, it is simple standard view of asp.net, using _Layout and renderview

Comment: controller goes like this:
public ActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordChangeObject obj)
        {
            TempData["changePasswordErrorMsg"] = null;
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return RedirectToAction("index", "Home", new { area = "Common" });
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(User.Identity.Name, obj.oldPassword)){
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {....

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, as far as it seems. So, i suspect that there is some problem with the js file or link to the js.

First of all, @required="true" is not necessary since the unobstructive validation in client side will do that for you. And I suspect that none of the client side validation works. You claim that only required attribute work for client side validation because you included @required="true". In fact, that is not part of microsoft unobstructive validation, rather it is html form validation.

My advice for you is to inspect the element and ensure that **jquery.validate.min.js** and **jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js** is included and the link is valid in your browser and at the same time check if there is any error in the console in web browser.

If it is valid link, try to remove both **headroom.js** from the link and refresh the page again.

If the above do not work, kindly reinstall nuget package for Microsoft JQuery Unobstructive validation.

Last but not least, I hope that you do Include this piece of code in your view page should you include the above script in your _Layout.cshtml but not in your view page itself.

```
@{
  Layout="LayoutFilePath here";
}
```

New update: Replace the jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobstrusive js to this two link. Change 5.0 to 4.0 if your are using MVC 4

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes i also suspected this, and accessed the js files in browser and they all open.
I tried commenting the headroom script and still the same result besides some features broke because of that.
And nothing particular under firefox console just the "Password fields present in a form with an insecure (http://)..." and "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal that two warning is not related with this. Try changing the two validate js link as what i have updated in this post.

Comment: I have Layout=... of cource in my razer code.
And it seems the above script inclusion is to make sure right libraries load..

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this approach if you are using Entity Framework.
Otherwise just include required namespace on top of your class.**

1: Create partial metadate class of PasswordChangeObject i.e

```
public partial class PasswordChangeObjectMetaData
{

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
//[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public String oldPassword { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "New Password is required")]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public String newPassword { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirming New Password is required")]
[StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 5 and 255 characters", MinimumLength = 5)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Compare("newPassword", ErrorMessage="Passwords do not Match!")]
public String confirmPassword { get; set; }

}
```

2: Create partial class for PasswordChangeObject which only includes get,set
and mention its metadata class on top , and remember to include required system namespace on top i.e

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
[MetadataType(typeof(PasswordChangeObjectMetaData))]

public partial class PasswordChangeObject
  {
    public String oldPassword { get; set; }
    public String newPassword { get; set; }
    public String confirmPassword { get; set; }
  }
```

3: In views use

```
@model Project.Models.PasswordChangeObjectMetaData
```

Comment: Its strange though, i will give it a try.

Comment: It will be great (for understanding) if you can explain why should it work and why not my approach is working?
Thankyou for your help